# DataBase Hit to load settings on page load - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i need to hit DB and load the settings file before every page loads. Am currently using MVC and am creating that call in constructor in All controllers.

Am not sure of what is the better way to handle this scenario ?? I read like we can use singleton class in this scenario.

Is it possible to have the data once and reuse across pages ? What is the best way ?

Some sample code snippets will help !

Comment: Are these user specific settings or are they application specific settings?

Answer (score 0):

Option one: you can used `Application_BeginRequest` in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        //something
}
```

Option two: create a global filter:

```
public class ActionLogFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         // do your stuff. This is run before control is passed to controller
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
    { 
        // do stuff here - control here is passed after controller is done with the action execution
    }
}
```

and then add controller to execution stack in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
```

and FilterConfig is usually looks like this:

```
public static class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new MyFilter());
    }
}
```

Option three: Create your global controller that overrides `OnActionExecuting` (see the filter example). Make your controllers to inherit from that global base controller.

I prefer option with filters. [Favour composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)